# Nodejs: Referencing constructor variables from instance variables

Tags: javascript, node.js, oop

I have a bit of an OOP issue in Javascript (Node).

I created a class called Bubble. This class has a constructor that takes in a token. Now, here's the problem:

```
class Bubble {
    
    constructor(token) {
        if (!token) throw new Error('No token');
        this.token = token;
    }

    first = new First(this.token)
    second = new Second(this.token)
    third = new Third(this.token)
```

If I perform `new Bubble("someToken").first`, a **null** token is passed. However, if I change *first*, *second* and *third* to functions and I perform `new Bubble("someToken").first()`, the exact token is passed successfully. I want to reference **first**, **second** and **third** as direct variables, not functions i.e `new Bubble("someToken").first`.

How do I go about this?

Comment: What's `new Bubble("someToken").first()`?

Comment: these lines should be in the constructor and preceded with `this`: `this.first = new First(this.token)` etc

Comment: what are First/Second/Third ? can you post syntactically correct code please?

Comment: Thanks, @georg. This worked perfectly fine. Can you post this as an answer to guide people that might encounter this problem in the future?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code uses [public class fields](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-fields), which are still not a part of the standard, although supported almost everywhere. The problem is, field initalizers are executed *before* the constructor, no matter where they are textually located:

```js
class A {
    field1 = console.log('field initializer 1')

    constructor() {
        console.log('constructor')
    }

    field2 = console.log('field initializer 2')
}

new A
```

Therefore, in `first = new First(this.token)`, the `token` is not defined yet. A workaround is to convert class fields into "normal" properties, initialized in the constructor:

```
class Bubble {
    constructor(token) {
        if (!token) throw new Error('No token');
        this.token = token;
        this.first = new First(this.token)
        ....etc
    }
```

Comment: That's not "a workaround", it's the only proper solution to create properties with values that depend on the constructor arguments.

Answer (score 3):

One option is to implement your class methods as [getters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get).  Here's how that might look like in your example:

```
class Bubble {
    
    constructor(token) {
        if (!token) throw new Error('No token');
        this.token = token;
    }
    
    get first() {
      return new First(this.token);
    }
    
    get second() {
      return new Second(this.token);
    }

    get third() {
      return new Third(this.token);
    }   
}
```

With those getters in place, accessing them would look like a regular property access for the caller.

```
const bubble = new Bubble("token");
bubble.first
bubble.second
bubble.third
```

Comment: This makes sense. Thanks for this.